# How to get html from a aspx website using swift

Tags: html, swift

I'm trying to make an app that fetches some text from a website. But I got an error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “XXX.aspx” couldn’t
>   be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=...}

I can open the website using my browser. I think the problem is about the aspx file. So how do I get the html from a aspx file? Here is the code I used:

Here is the code I used:

```swift
let myURLString = "https://https://nutrition.sa.ucsc.edu/shortmenu.aspx?sName=UC+Santa+Cruz+Dining&locationNum=25&locationName=Porter+Kresge+Dining+Hall&naFlag=1&WeeksMenus=UCSC+-+This+Week%27s+Menus&myaction=read&dtdate=9%2f2%2f2019"

guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        do {
            let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
            print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: I get `Server Error in '/' Application` error with your link? Can you check it on browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get html from your link like this. But i think your link is broken. It gives server error.

```swift
let myURLString = "https://nutrition.sa.ucsc.edu/shortmenu.aspx?sName=UC+Santa+Cruz+Dining&locationNum=25&locationName=Porter+Kresge+Dining+Hall&naFlag=1&WeeksMenus=UCSC+-+This+Week%27s+Menus&myaction=read&dtdate=9%2f2%2f2019"


let url = URL(string: myURLString)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
    (
    data, response, error) in

    let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
    print(dataString)

}
task.resume()
```

Comment: This is a university domain. Maybe there is some restrictions for attempt by unauthorized people.

Comment: There is no login kinda thing on that website. Maybe I'm using the wrong way to request the content?

Comment: Maybe. But i think if you cannot see any error on this link probably there is a firewall on your network. Can you check with different network?

Comment: I can view the website on browser using the same network. I'm thinking is there any way I can use the webkit or something actually load the website in background and convert it to html code?

Comment: ok I figured it out. I have to request the main page first and then this one. But thanks anyway